# FileNet Bulk Search and Update

Tags: batch-processing, filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine

I have a requirement wherein, I have to update document metadata for millions of documents in the objectstore. So I wrote a simple java stand-alone with the below approach

```
SearchSQL documentSearchSQL = new SearchSQL();
String selectQuery = "Id ";
String classSymbolicName="Document_Class_Name";
String myAlias1 = "r";
String whereClause="r.Document_Type_Code='DIRMKTGDOC'and VersionStatus=1"
boolean subClassesToo=false;
documentSearchSQL.setSelectList(selectQuery);
documentSearchSQL.setFromClauseInitialValue(classSymbolicName, myAlias1, subClassesToo);
documentSearchSQL.setWhereClause(whereClause);

UpdatingBatch updatingBatch =null;
SearchScope searchScope = new SearchScope(p8ObjectStore);
RepositoryRowSet rowSet = searchScope.fetchRows(documentSearchSQL, new Integer(10000), null, new Boolean(true));
PageIterator pageIterator = rowSet.pageIterator();
RepositoryRow row;
Document document = null;

while(pageIterator.nextPage()){
Object[] rowArray = pageIterator.getCurrentPage();
updatingBatch = UpdatingBatch.createUpdatingBatchInstance(p8ObjectStore.get_Domain(),RefreshMode.NO_REFRESH); 
for (int i = 0; i < rowArray.length; i++) {
row= (RepositoryRow)rowArray[i];
Properties documentProps = row.getProperties();
document = Factory.Document.fetchInstance(p8ObjectStore, documentProps.getIdValue("Id"), null);
// I have the metadata symbolic name and its values within HashMap. So iterating Map to set the values
for(Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> documentMetadata : documentMetadataValues.entrySet()){
document.getProperties().putObjectValue(documentMetadata.getKey(), documentMetadata.getValue().get(1));
}
updatingBatch.add(document, null);
}
updatingBatch.updateBatch();
```

When I ran a query on docVersion, I found around 700K documents matching the criteria and was expecting all of them to get updated. When I ran the program, it updated about 390k documents and then gave error

```
com.filenet.api.exception.EngineRuntimeException: FNRCA0031E: API_UNABLE_TO_USE_CONNECTION: The URI for server communication cannot be determined from the connection object http://server:port/wsi/FNCEWS40MTOM. Message was: Connection refused: connect
```

Is there a better way to achieve this? Also, I will be using, component queue to run this tool in production.

Comment: If you are using 5.2.1 you may want to look into "sweeps"

Comment: I agree with @ChristopherPowell, you'd be better off using sweeps or bulk actions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 better options actually to do this, either by using the script-based bulk actions or the sweeps.

---

### Bulk Actions

You can apply bulk actions to the search results of a query. The application of these actions occurs either while the query runs or after the query runs.

1. Access the **object store search** in the administration console
2. On the **SQL view tab**, enter an appropriate query.
3. On the **Bulk Actions tab**, select **Enable**.
4. In the Script section, select **Run script**.
5. Enter your JavaScript code into the Script field. For more information, see an example below.
6. Click **Run**. The administration console runs the query and the JavaScript action.

```js
importClass(Packages.com.filenet.api.property.Properties);
importClass(Packages.com.filenet.api.constants.RefreshMode);

function OnCustomProcess(CEObject) {
  CEObject.refresh();
  CEObject.getProperties().putValue("DocumentTitle", "Test1");
  CEObject.save(RefreshMode.REFRESH);
}
```

For more on this you can check the knowledge center  [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSNW2F_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.ce.admin.tasks.doc/p8pcc193.htm)

---

### Custom Sweep Job

Alternatively you can use the a custom sweep job. A sweep is an instance of a background service that you configure to process objects in a database table.
If an object meets a configured criteria, the sweep performs an action on the object.
The sweep consists of a **sweep action** and a **sweep job**

1. In the domain navigation pane, click the **object store**. In the object
   store navigation pane, right-click the **Sweep Management > Sweep
   Actions** folder and click **New Sweep Action**.
2. Select **action type**. for this example, lets select Java script, an example is listed below, and finish the wizard.
3. In the domain navigation pane, select the **object store**.
   In the object store navigation pane, select the **Sweep Management > Job Sweeps > Custom Jobs** folder and Click **New**, refer to the action we just created, and finish the wizard.
   Now you are all set! run the sweep job

```js
importPackage(Packages.com.filenet.api.core);
importPackage(Packages.com.filenet.api.constants);
importPackage(Packages.com.filenet.api.exception);
importPackage(Packages.com.filenet.api.sweep);
importPackage(Packages.com.filenet.api.engine);

// Implement for custom job and queue sweeps.
function onSweep(sweepObject, sweepItems) {
  var hcc = HandlerCallContext.getInstance();
  hcc.traceDetail("Entering CustomSweepHandler.onSweep");
  hcc.traceDetail("sweepObject = " +
    sweepObject.getProperties().getIdValue(PropertyNames.ID) +
    "sweepItems.length = " + sweepItems.length);

  // Iterate the sweepItems and change the class.
  idx = 0;
  for (idx = 0; idx < sweepItems.length; idx++) {
    // At the top of your loop, always check to make sure 
    // that the server is not shutting down. 
    // If it is, clean up and return control to the server.
    if (hcc != null && hcc.isShuttingDown()) {
      throw new EngineRuntimeException(ExceptionCode.E_BACKGROUND_TASK_TERMINATED,
        this.constructor.name + " is terminating prematurely because the server is shutting down");
    }

    var item = sweepItems[idx].getTarget();
    String msg = "sweepItems[" + idx + "]= " + item.getProperties().getIdValue("ID");
    hcc.traceDetail(msg);

    try {
      var CEObject = Document(item);
      CEObject.getProperties().putValue("DocumentTitle", "Test1");
      CEObject.save(RefreshMode.NO_REFRESH);

      // Set outcome to PROCESSED if item processed successfully.
      sweepItems[idx].setOutcome(SweepItemOutcome.PROCESSED,
        "item processed by " + this.constructor.name);
    }
    // Set failure status on objects that fail to process.
    catch (ioe) {
      sweepItems[idx].setOutcome(SweepItemOutcome.FAILED, "CustomSweepHandler: " +
        ioe.rhinoException.getMessage());
    }
  }
  hcc.traceDetail("Exiting CustomSweepHandler.onSweep");
}

/* 
 * Called automatically when the handler is invoked by a custom sweep job 
 * or sweep policy. Specify properties required by the handler, if any.
 * If you return an empty array, then all properties are fetched.
 */
function getRequiredProperties() {
  var pnames = ['Id', 'DocumentTitle'];
  return pnames.toString();
}
```

For more on the sweep jobs, please check the link [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSNW2F_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.ce.admin.tasks.doc/p8pcc346.htm)